# convert string to int with losing everything but digits

Tags: c#, .net

I have string

```
string a = "234234324\r\n";
```

I want to parse this string into integer with losing this `\r\n` part, so `int` should contain only digits from string a like `int b = 234234324`;

p.s. string does not necessarily contain the `\r\n` part, point is that I want to use only digits from string.

I tried with `Convert.ToInt32(a)` but I have error.

Comment: What if you have `string a = "a234234324\r\n123";`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici that will not be the case for sure in my case, but you pointed very well.

Comment: You're number is pretty close to `Int32.MaxValue`(2147483647), maybe you should use `long.parse()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int b = int.Parse(new string(a.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) -- that removes all leading and trailing whitespace.

```
int b = int.Parse(a.Trim());
```

Comment: p.s. string does not neccessarily contains \r\n part, point is that I want to use only digits from string.
(in the op's update)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string a = "234234324\r\n";
string justNumbers = new String(a.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Note: Obviously, this requires LINQ.

Now you can convert the string without fear of non-numerics being in the string, like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(justNumbers);
```

Comment: [Jamie Zawinski on Regex](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `Trim` followed by `Int32.TryParse`

```
int b = Int32.TryParse(a.Trim(), out num);
```

Comment: `Trim()` does not remove the non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you need to add a reference to *Microsoft.VisualBasic*):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = "234234324\r\n";
        int b = int.Parse(Conversion.Val(a).ToString());
    }
}
```